# A working login with primefaces, spring, hibernate, glassfish, mysql on netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, primefaces

I am using this site [This site](http://www.pointerunits.com/2012/11/simple-login-application-using-spring.html) for learning spring and hibernate in primefaces. I however getting an error

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /login.xhtml @31,125 action="#{login.spring}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'login' resolved to null
```

My login.xhtml (primefaces)

```
 <h:inputText id="username" value="#{spring_login.username}" label="UserName"/>
<h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{spring_login.password}" label="PassWord"/>
<h:commandButton  value="LOGIN" action="#{login.spring}"  />
```

LoginController.java

```
@RequestMapping("/Login_spring")
    public class LoginController {        
        @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView processCredentials
            (@RequestParam("username")String username,@RequestParam("password")String password){
            String message="invalid credentials";
            if(!username.equals("") && !password.equals("")){
                if(username.equals(username)){
                    try {
                        message="welcome "+ username + " !";
                        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
                        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)context.getExternalContext().getResponse();
                        response.sendRedirect("index.xhtml");
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
             } 
            return new ModelAndView("results", "message", message);
        }
    }
```

I have been all over the internet for a working example on A working login with primefaces, spring, hibernate, glassfish, mysql on netbeans 7.4

Comment: [Asking an off-topic question on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41060/a-working-login-with-primefaces-spring-hibernate-glassfish-mysql-on-netbeans) is not the same as having been all over the internet.

Comment: Why are you using SPEL inside action value on your login.xhtml? Like exception explained, you are trying to access "spring" attribute ( login.spring ), but you can't because "login" is null!